# Is there audio of Malcolm X's original The Ballot or the Bullet speech?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, civil-rights

Malcolm X's famous [Ballot or the Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballot_or_the_Bullet) speech - his first after leaving the Nation of Islam and "ranked 7th in the top 100 American speeches of the 20th century by 137 leading scholars of American public address" - was given just twice; first in Cleveland, Ohio on the 3 April 1964, and then in Detroit, Michigan on the 12 April 1964.

According to [a footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballot_or_the_Bullet#cite_note-3) on that Wikipedia page, recordings exist of both versions, but of the many audio recordings I've come across on YouTube, *all* of them seem to be from the later Michigan speech. This is significant because based on the transcripts, the [Ohio version](http://www.edchange.org/multicultural/speeches/malcolm_x_ballot.html) seems to be a more eloquent speech that makes Malcolm X's case much more clearly, with the [Michigan version](https://americanradioworks.publicradio.org/features/blackspeech/mx.html) seeming more informal and improvised and covering less content.

Where can an audio version of the original Ohio speech actually be found?

*N.B.* Audio of the two recordings can be differentiated based on the first line: the Michigan speech refers to a "Reverend Cleage", whereas in Ohio it refers to a "Brother Lomax".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The audiotape of both the Cleveland and Detroit versions of speech is found at the Schomburg Center Oral History Collection.  An in-person appointment is required to hear the audiotape.

[https://legacycatalog.nypl.org/search~S1?/jSc+Audio+C-176/jsc+audio+c++++176/-3%2C-1%2C0%2CB/exact&FF=jsc+audio+c++++176&1%2C2%2C](https://legacycatalog.nypl.org/search%7ES1?/jSc+Audio+C-176/jsc+audio+c++++176/-3%2C-1%2C0%2CB/exact&FF=jsc+audio+c++++176&1%2C2%2C)

I was able to find a small excerpt of it on YouTube.

https://youtu.be/nqFhozA8sYM?si=dw_WZPYdvFw9f6vT